# Ellipse equation which lies on $x=y$

Tags: geometry

How do I write an ellipse equation which lies on the line $x=y$?

I know its vertex are $(\pm3\sqrt{2},\pm3\sqrt{2})$ and $(\pm\sqrt{14},\mp\sqrt{14})$. Also, its center is the origin. But certainly, when I plot
$$\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{y^2}{14}=1$$
it lies on $x$-axis.

Comment: You have to rotate it 45 degrees. See here if it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9OWnuarYuc

Comment: @Gordon that's what I thought. But how am I able to do it?

Comment: Doing so requires a mapping from $x$ to $x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta$ and $y$ to $x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ellipse rotated by $45^\circ$ like this has an equation of the form:

$$A(x-y)^2+B(x+y)^2=1$$
Now you can just substitute the $(x,y)$-coordinates of the vertices to find $A$ and $B$. You will find that they have a very simple form.

Note that the axes are not $\sqrt{18}$ and $\sqrt{14}$, as you might expect; the distances of those vertices from the origin are multiplied by $\sqrt2$ by the rotation. So your equation
$$\frac{x^2}{18}+\frac{y^2}{14}=1$$
actually defines a smaller ellipse.

Comment: What I got was: the equation on the $x=y$ axis, is $$\dfrac{x^2}{36}+\dfrac{y^2}{28}=1$$ But when I triy to change the variables to using $x\cos45º-y\sin45º$ and $-x\sin45º+y\cos45º$, it doesn't work.

Comment: @mvfs314: Substitute $(x,y)=(\sqrt{14},-\sqrt{14})$ into the equation $A(x-y)^2+B(x+y)^2=1$. This will give you $A$. Now substitute $(x,y)=(3\sqrt 2,3\sqrt 2)$: this will give you $B$.